# SSRS Report Builder how to hide specific textbox exporting to Excel

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to hide two textboxes from my DrillDown Report when exporting to excel but with no luck.

[image]

I also add expression to the visibility property of each textbox as below but still doesn't work:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCEL",true,false)
```

as well as

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML" OR Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", false, true)
```

The two textboxes "**ExpandAll**" and "**CollapseAll**" are being used just to refresh the same report with a parameter to expend/collapse the rows in the drilldown report which are not necessary to be shown in excel when being exported.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Ref: [MSDN: Changing Reports at Run-Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234.aspx)

Ref: [MSDN: RenderFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your second expression is correct,

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML" OR Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", false, true)
```

Make sure the Action property after you click on **ExpandAll** or **CollapseAll** actually points to `the same report/same URL/same directory` as your current one. For eg,

```
"http://localhost/ReportServer/MyReports/MyReportName"
```

[image]

Comment: You are right, I happened to save the report to my local copy located in a specific directory and forgot to upload nor to save it back to the report server. I might have been confused out of thinking too much for a while :D . Also, the second expression is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For SSRS in 2012, the correct syntax would be:

`=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCELOPENXML",true,false)`

They cleverly changed it for the 2012 edition.

FWIW, your 2nd attempt had `, false, true )` where it should be `, true , false )` .  This is a really unintuitive property in SSRS, the UI calls it Visible but the actual property is Hidden, so everyone always gets confused ...